# Where is my old partition in mysql show create table?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I am keep adding daily base partition for a table as e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE tblData PARTITION BY RANGE (to_days(`dataInsertDateTime`)) (
PARTITION p20 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2012-12-25')),
PARTITION p21 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2012-12-26')),
PARTITION p22 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2012-12-27')),
PARTITION p23 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2012-12-28')),
PARTITION p24 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2012-12-29'))
)
```

When I run this show create table tblData is only shows me the partition p20 to p24. I am wondering where is all my previous p0-p19? Is it get dissolve when each time I run the alter table to add partitions?

Comment: I suspect you're actually repartitioning the entire table like that (and making the p20 partition very big). From the documentation, I think you need a `REORGANIZE PARTITION` clause. I'm sure a MySQL DBA will answer it soon and take my credit :)

Comment: @phil so what should I be doing to keep adding new partition when I need them?

Comment: As @Phil's comment, see the documentation: **[Management of RANGE and LIST Partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-management-range-list.html)**, and the paragraph: *"To add a new range or list partition to a previously partitioned table, use the `ALTER TABLE ... ADD PARTITION` statement. For tables ..."*

Comment: @ypercube so I guess I am missing ALTER TABLE tblData ADD PARTITION. Can I say I am missing the word ADD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have plessthanmax part? When you set up a partition (that "moves" daily) the best practice is to set up a plessthanmax part to avoid errors. Each day you create a new partition and reorganise the plessthanmax like this :

For December 29

```
ALTER TABLE BtblData REORGANIZE PARTITION plessthanmax INTO (PARTITION p24 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2012-12-29')), partition plessthanmax values less than maxvalue)
```

For December 30

```
ALTER TABLE BtblData REORGANIZE PARTITION plessthanmax INTO (PARTITION p25 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2012-12-30')), partition plessthanmax values less than maxvalue)
```

Max.

Comment: so I am missing plessthanmax and reorganise right? Anything am I missing ? Sorry kind of new to partition so trying out and learning new stuff.